# Total brokers with atleast one purchase weekly in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

| cid | Company name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cname 1 |
| 2 | cname2 |

| bid | cid | broker name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | broker 1 |
| 2 | 1 | broker 2 |

| pid | bid | purchase date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-05-01 00:20:30 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-02 13:20:30 |

I have above tables. I would like to fetch data weekly data of brokers with at least one purchase in a week.

| week start date | No of brokers |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-03 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2021-04-10 00:00:00 | 20 |

Also I would like to fetch data weekly data of companies with at least one purchase in a week.

| week start date | No of companies |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-03 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2021-04-10 00:00:00 | 20 |

postgres sql queries.

Comment: What did you try, what's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()` and then count the brokers and companies using `count(distinct)`:

```
select date_trunc('week', purchase_date) as week,
       count(distinct p.bid) as num_brokers,
       count(distinct b.cid) as num_companies
from purchases p join
     brokers b
     on p.bid = b.id
group by week;
```

You would use `count(*)` to get the number of purchases.